# Visual Studio 2010 Web Publish missing a file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I'm finding that when publishing a website from Visual Studio its not uploading one of my files. Its a Razor file with a '.cshtml' extension (its doing the others!) and its part of the project.

Any ideas why it would exclude it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right-click on the file and go to *Properties*.

Under the file's properties, make sure that *Build Action* is set to **Content**. Otherwise it won't be published via web deploy.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I'll exclude my web.config file when deploying, so it doesn't override my production server configuration.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem deploying from TFService from a Build. Any idea how to apply this setting there? Thanks (using VS 2012 Express)

Comment: Any idea why some cshtml files don't become content when they obviously are?

Comment: @ErikBergstedt, my quick guess at this, is that it has something to do with files that may get excluded from the project at some point and need to be included again.  Could be what I was seeing

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had a couple of config files that weren't being deployed even though they had "Build Action" set to Content. I fixed the problem by excluding them from the project and include them again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to Exclude and re-Include the files. When that didn't work I checked my .proj file and the files were in fact missing. I had to add the files into the .proj file manually. That worked for me